# Blinking textbox value using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, textbox

I am using following code to blink a textbox value, but it is not supported by Firefox, IE. How can i achieve? May i do with fade to function.. If yes means help me.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#blinkchk").click(function(){
var a=$("#text").val();
a.blink();
});

});
</script>

<body>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="blinkchk" value="Blink" />Blink
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first give the css, `transition: color 0.3s;`

and then:

```
$("#blinkchk").click(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#text').css('color','transparent');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#text').css('color','black');
        },500);
    },1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8ebF6/

Comment: @ Amin Jafari ,If i uncheck this checkbox need to stop blinking. Is there any way like $("#blinkchk").click(function() for uncheck the checkbox?

Comment: here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/8ebF6/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this. exactly what you want

```
$("#blinkchk").click(function(){

    setInterval(function() { 
       $("#text").removeClass().addClass("m1")
    }, 400);

       setInterval(function() { 
       $("#text").removeClass().addClass("m2")
    }, 800);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/55Gwu/2/)

Comment: this will make the whole element blink, not the text individually

Comment: remove textarea and make it as span or div it will work. question has textarea so i will put that one

Comment: @ Amin Jafari  - see another demo for you

Comment: I didn't mean like that, check out my answer and see the fiddle to see what I'm talking about

Comment: as you can see here (http://jsfiddle.net/8ebF6/) only the text is blinking, not the whole container (which is a textarea in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this for compatibility:

```
<style>
.blink_on {
opacity: 1;
}
.blink_off {
opacity: 0;
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#blinkchk").click(function(){
setInterval(function() {
if($("#text").hasClass('blink_on')) {
$("#text").removeClass('blink_on');
$("#text").addClass('blink_off');
}
else {
$("#text").addClass('blink_on');
}
},300);
});

});
</script>

<body>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="blinkchk" value="Blink" />Blink
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin for jQuery which brings back blink functionality if you're keen on hurting peoples eyes! It allows you to simply use the following to get something to blink:

`$('.blink').blink();`

http://www.antiyes.com/jquery-blink-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
$("#blinkchk").click(function(){
    setInterval(function(){$("#text").fadeOut(200,function(){
      $(this).fadeIn(200);
    })},400);

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mqEh3/11/)**